# Laravel API 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am making simple API with **Laravel 5.4** and I have problem. I created routing and some data for tests but when I testing if routing work properly with Postman by putting `localhost:8888/{projectname}/api/v1/meeting` it shows me `error 404 page not found`. What am I doing wrong?

**routes/api.php**

```
<?php    
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::resource('meeting', 'MeetingController', [
        'except' => ['edit', 'create']
    ]);

    Route::resource('meeting/registration', 'RegistrationController', [
        'only' => ['store', 'destroy']
    ]);

    Route::post('user', [
        'uses' => 'AuthController@store'
    ]);

    Route::post('user/signin', [
        'uses' => 'AuthController@signin'
    ]);
});
```

**MeetingController**

```
<?php    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;    
use App\Http\Requests;    
class MeetingController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->middleware('name');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

}
```

**RegistrationController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }

    public function signin(Request $request)
    {
        return "It works!";
    }
}
```

Output of command `php artisan route:list`:

```
    +--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                        | Name                 | Action                                              | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                          |                      | Closure                                             | web        |
|        | POST      | api/v1/meeting                             | meeting.store        | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@store        | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/meeting                             | meeting.index        | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@index        | api        |
|        | POST      | api/v1/meeting/registration                | registration.store   | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@store   | api        |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/meeting/registration/{registration} | registration.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@destroy | api        |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/meeting/{meeting}                   | meeting.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@destroy      | api        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/v1/meeting/{meeting}                   | meeting.update       | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@update       | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/meeting/{meeting}                   | meeting.show         | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@show         | api        |
|        | POST      | api/v1/user                                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@store           | api        |
|        | POST      | api/v1/user/signin                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@signin          | api        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: The `api.php` routes are already prefixed with `/api`. You don't need to add this again yourself. With your current set-up, your route is `localhost:8888/{projectname}/api/api/v1/meeting`

Comment: I tried also delete api with routes and it shows The same error

Comment: You don't need `/{projectname}` in your request url.

Comment: Tried `localhost:8888/api/v1/meeting` ?

Comment: Yes and it shows same error 404

Comment: Please post the results of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: here is result of php artisan route:list

`POST      | api/v1/meeting                             | meeting.store        | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@store        | api
GET|HEAD  | api/v1/meeting                             | meeting.index        | App\Http\Controllers\MeetingController@index        | api POST      | api/v1/meeting/registration                | registration.store   | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@store   | api DELETE    | api/v1/meeting/registration/{registration} | registration.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@destroy | api`

Comment: What about homepage and other pages?

Comment: @Michael Chen When i go to `localhost:8888/{project-folder}/{project-name}/public` it shows normal laravel welcome page so it working properly. Only problem is with api. Nothing of solutions that was below doesn't work for me.

Comment: So, what about `localhost:8888/{project-folder}/{project-name}/public/api/v1/meeting` ?

Comment: @cbaconnier you are a genius it stars working

Comment: I am confused why you need `project-folder` and `project-name` in you url?

Comment: becouse in my htdocs folder I have project folder and I created another folder with command composer create laravel/laravel project-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4, your `routes/api.php` should look like this:

```
<?php

Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('meeting', 'MeetingController', [
        'except' => ['edit', 'create']
    ]);

    Route::resource('meeting/registration', 'RegistrationController', [
        'only' => ['store', 'destroy']
    ]);

    Route::post('user', [
        'uses' => 'AuthController@store'
    ]);

    Route::post('user/signin', [
        'uses' => 'AuthController@signin'
    ]);
});
```

For more info, visit their docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-prefixes).

Comment: You are right I changed it but still got 404 problem. Maybe there is other problem not with routes/api.php file.

Comment: ahh can you give me whats your server host config?

Comment: Worked for me in Laravel 6.2

Answer (score 10):

as in version 5.4 the api is already added in the end points so no need to add 'api' again in the url.

Please change from:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {

}
```

To

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {

}
```

Comment: It's not the problem with this route becouse I change it as you said and still have the same trouble

Comment: @KonradUciechowski ok please try it with localhost:8888/{projectname}/index.php/api/v1/meeting

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve`or apache/nginx/...?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer adding **Accept application/json** header on client side to get JSON response. That’s the most straightforward way, but you would be surprised how many developers forget it, or don’t even know about it.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use /api in your routes keep it simple like

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() { //code goes here}
php artisan route:list
```

this will list all your routes if there is any error in the route then it will not be listed here.